# Android Localization: why doesn't my app localize language?

Tags: android, localization

I am localizing my application. I have 2 projects on eclipse; one is the library.

I have created a subfolder of the res/values folder for the italian localization (both in the library and in the other project). When I open my app (with the italian language set) the app displays the english (default) strings.

My folders are organized like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values-it` should be directly under `res`, not in `res/values`.